# sending XMPP IQ packet to server with ITEM TAG?

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am working in chat application. In which I am using XMPP protocol.I need to send IQ stanza with Item tag.my full IQ stanza as follows.My question is how to add ITEM tag to IQ Stanza?

```
`<iq type="set">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:livrequest">
<item jid="user@localhost" startid="456" status="requesting"/>
</query>
</iq>
```

Comment: Yes.I found solution for above question.

Comment: Can you please add your solution link @BABUK